# ICanHaz Templates Blocked/Filtered in Browser

Tags: javascript, mustache, icanhaz.js

One of our clients is having trouble loading our website content stored in ICanHaz Templates. Script tag(s) like the following are completely missing from the source code when rendered to the browser.

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/html"> .... </script>
```

This is causing a javascript error when calling

```
ich.myTemplate(templateData);
```

As well, calling ich.grabTemplates() doesn't work because no templates are rendered. We have over 250 clients and only 1 of them is reporting this issue. The templates are loaded from the same domain as the rest of the site.

It is occurring in both the IE 9 & 10 and the latest version of Chrome on their machines. OS - Windows 7.

We are thinking this is an Internet Options setting/Browser setting/firewall issue. Any ideas? Having trouble reproducing.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Debugging steps to take: 1) Verify with View/Source in the browser that the templates are not in the page source. 2) Look in the network tab of the Chrome debugger and verify that you don't see the templates transferred with the page. 3) Verify that the templates are actually present in the source file on server. 4) Get some sort of http watcher program on the server to watch what is being sent out from the server to see if they are included in the bits being sent out from the server.  Based on those results, you should at least know where to look next (client, server or transport in between).

Comment: Thanks for your comment jfriend00. We have resolved the issue just this morning. Our clients proxy server was filtering out parts of our site because it was not added to their white list of sites. Once they added it everything worked great!